# Laravel passport use two providers and same route for two middleware

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I wanted to use two providers and guard for passport api:auth. I have two guards and providers user and merchant. I wanted to enable access my api for  both user and merchant for same route like I have an route api/vendors. this route can access both user types user and merchant models.

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
    'merchant-api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'merchant',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
],


'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
    'merchant' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Merchant::class,
    ],
],
```

Merchant Model

```
 <?php

 namespace App;

 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
 use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;

class Merchant extends Model
{
   use HasApiTokens;

   public function getMerchantByAppIdAppSecret($app_id, $app_secret){
   return $this->where('app_id', $app_id)
               ->where('app_secret', $app_secret)
               ->first();
    }
 }
```

user model

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
  use Notifiable, HasRoles, HasApiTokens, LogsActivity;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'email', 'password', 'created_at',
];

/**
 * Activity log config
 *
 * @var string[]
 */
}
```

routes
//for merchant
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:merchant-api'], function() {

```
  Route::resource('vendors', 'VendorController');
});
//for user
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function() {

  Route::resource('vendors', 'VendorController');
});
```

but this showing me 500 error

```
    Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException: Route [login] not defined.
```

Comment: i think you have issue in route file check route file login route is available and if yes then check name of login route

Comment: @Abhishek yes login route have present at my route file

Comment: i hope you auth middelware is like this : protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('login');
        }
    }

Comment: @Abhishek No this condition not have at there